# How to implement reversal of a stack in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class StackClass<T> implements StackADT<T>
{
    private int maxStackSize;  //variable to store the
                               //maximum stack size
    private int stackTop;      //variable to point to
                               //the top of the stack
    private T[] list;  //array of reference variables

       //Default constructor
       //Create an array of the size 100 to implement the stack.
       //Postcondition: The variable list contains the base
       //               address of the array, stackTop = 0,
       //               and maxStackSize = 100.
    public StackClass()
    {
        maxStackSize = 100;
        stackTop = 0;         //set stackTop to 0
        list = (T[]) new Object[maxStackSize]; //create the array
    }//end default constructor

       //Constructor with a parameter
       //Create an array of the size stackSize to implement the
       //stack.
       //Postcondition: The variable list contains the base
       //               address of the array, stackTop = 0,
       //               and maxStackSize = stackSize.
    public StackClass(int stackSize)
    {
        if (stackSize <= 0)
        {
            System.err.println("The size of the array to "
                             + "implement the stack must be "
                             + "positive.");
            System.err.println("Creating an array of the size 100.");

            maxStackSize = 100;
        }
        else
            maxStackSize = stackSize; //set the stack size to
                                      //the value specified by
                                      //the parameter stackSize
        stackTop = 0;    //set stackTop to 0
        list = (T[]) new Object[maxStackSize]; //create the array
    }//end constructor

       //Method to initialize the stack to an empty state.
       //Postcondition: stackTop = 0
    public void initializeStack()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stackTop; i++)
            list[i] = null;

        stackTop = 0;
    }//end initializeStack

       //Method to determine whether the stack is empty.
       //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is empty;
       //               otherwise, returns false.
    public boolean isEmptyStack()
    {
        return (stackTop == 0);
    }//end isEmptyStack

       //Method to determine whether the stack is full.
       //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is full;
       //               otherwise, returns false.
    public boolean isFullStack()
    {
        return (stackTop == maxStackSize);
    }//end isFullStack

       //Method to add newItem to the stack.
       //Precondition: The stack exists and is not full.
       //Postcondition: The stack is changed and newItem
       //               is added to the top of stack.
       //               If the stack is full, the method
       //               throws StackOverflowException
    public void push(T newItem) throws StackOverflowException
    {
        if (isFullStack())
            throw new StackOverflowException();

        list[stackTop] = newItem; //add newItem at the
                                  //top of the stack
        stackTop++;               //increment stackTop
    }//end push

       //Method to return a reference to the top element of
       //the stack.
       //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
       //Postcondition: If the stack is empty, the method
       //               throws StackUnderflowException;
       //               otherwise, a reference to the top
       //               element of the stack is returned.
    public T peek() throws StackUnderflowException
    {
        if (isEmptyStack())
            throw new StackUnderflowException();

        return (T) list[stackTop - 1];
    }//end peek

       //Method to remove the top element of the stack.
       //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
       //Postcondition: The stack is changed and the top
       //               element is removed from the stack.
       //               If the stack is empty, the method
       //               throws StackUnderflowException
    public void pop() throws StackUnderflowException
    {
        if (isEmptyStack())
           throw new StackUnderflowException();

        stackTop--;       //decrement stackTop
        list[stackTop] = null;
    }//end pop


}
```

I'm trying to implement a reverseStack operation that copies the elements of a stack in reverse order onto another stack. So far I've come up with the following...

```
public void reverseStack(StackClass<T> otherStack)
        {
           StackClass<T> newStack = new StackClass<T>();

           StackObj obj = null;
           while ( (obj = this.pop()) != null ) {
                      otherStack.push(obj);
                      newStack.push(obj);
           }

           // Now push back from newStack to this stack
           while ( (obj = newStack.pop() ) != null ) {
                     this.push(obj);
           }
        }
```

But I'm having issues with the part of my code that is

```
StackObj obj = null;
while ( (obj = this.pop()) != null ) {
    otherStack.push(obj);
    newStack.push(obj);
   }
```

Because a StackObj class was never defined. Yet, I don't see what else I could define obj as because my pop procedure doesn't return a value. Any ideas?

Thanks (and no this isn't homework...I'm trying to learn Java on my own through exercises).

Comment: `my pop procedure doesn't return a value` - why doesn't it return a value?

Comment: Silly question, why do you create a StackObj? Why not taking objects from STACK A and just pushing them onto STACK B? Since Stack is LIFO it will automatically reverse the order...

Comment: Yeah but what can I use inside my while loop instead of `obj = this.pop()` then?

Comment: You can directly push the pop()-result. newStack.push(this.pop());

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use your type T like this:

```
public StackClass<T> reverseStack()
    {
       StackClass<T> newStack = new StackClass<T>();

       T obj = null;
       while ( (obj = this.pop()) != null ) {
                  newStack.push(obj);
       }

       return newStack; //Shallow reversed stack
    }
```

Since your stack contains objects of type T, you should also threat them like a T.

Something to keep in mind [Deep vs Shallow Copy](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/deepCopying.htm). You are doing a shallow copy, is that what you want? :)

Comment: Do you mean (obj = this.peek()) instead of (obj = this.pop()) because peek returns a T type object but pop does not.

Comment: No I actually meant pop. You can also work with peek but then you must pop the object in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to create a new array and insert them in reverse order. The code below does this but it also returns a new `StackClass` leaving the current one unchanged. It does that through making a `private` constructor for the `StackClass` which it passes the array directly into the class.

```
/**
 * Internal constructor
 * @param list
 * @param stackTop
 */
private StackClass(T[] list, int stackTop) {
    this.list = list;
    this.maxStackSize = list.length;
    this.stackTop = stackTop;
}

/**
 * Reverses the current stack and returns it. The current instance remains unchanged
 * @return
 */
public StackClass<T> reverse() {
    // create our new stack
    T[] newList = (T[]) new Object[maxStackSize];
    // loop through the current stack in reverse pushing them onto the new stack in the correct order
    for(int i=stackTop-1;i>=0;i--) {
        newList[(stackTop-1)-i] = list[i];
    }
    // create our new stack for returning
    return new StackClass<T>(newList, stackTop);
}
```

Now if you want to write a method that changes the current stack its not to far off this code.